# Dynamic v-icon in vuetify template

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm currently  trying to render dynamic `v-icon` components in my `vuetify` template.
I have a list of item for which I want to set a specific icon per item.

So my list is :

```
  <v-list-item
    v-for="application in installedApplications"
    :key="application.id"
    :to="{ name: application.verboseName + 'Dashboard' }"
    link>
    <v-list-item-icon>
      <v-tooltip right>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-icon v-on="on">mdi-{{ application.icon }}</v-icon>
        </template>
        <span>{{ application.verboseName }}</span>
      </v-tooltip>
    </v-list-item-icon>
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title>
        {{ application.verboseName }}
      </v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
```

You can see that I loop my `installedApplications` to populate my sidebar with icons.
My `application`s have an attribute `icon` so that doing `application.icon` returns something like `home`, `archive` or whatever icon name we can find [here](https://materialdesignicons.com/).

Whereas doing `<v-icon>mdi-home</v-icon` will display properly the desired icon, I'd like to be able to do `<v-icon>mdi-{{ application.icon }}</v-icon>` (I tried in my template above) but it doesn't work.

Any idea to solve that ? Maybe I missed some detail ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this line:

```
<v-icon v-on="on">mdi-{{ application.icon }}</v-icon>
```

to:

```
<v-icon v-on="on"> {{ `mdi-${application.icon}` }} </v-icon>
```

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/begueradj-the-sasster/pen/abvoaZq?editable=true&editors=101) demo I just created for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It's funny but finally my version worked too, whereas for a while it didn't.